# How to pass a void function with variable number of argument in a queue for a thread pool?

Tags: c++, templates, lambda

I have been trying to implement some kind of thread pool. I need to get some tasks in a `Queue` and these tasks might have some arguments.

```
template <typename FUNCTION, typename... ARGS>
    void push_function(const FUNCTION &function, const ARGS &...args){
        push_function([function, args...]{ function(args...); });
    }

    template <typename FUNCTION>

void push_function(FUNCTION &function){
    {
    std::unique_lock<std::mutex> lock(queue_mutex);
    queue.push(std::function<void()>(function));
    }   
    cv.notify_one();
}
```

I get the error :
`must use '.*' or '->' to call pointer-to-member function in 'function(...)'...` because of this line

```
push_function([function, args...]{ function(args...); });
```

Answer (score 0):

You are pushing a non static member function.

1. These need a this pointer.
2. You need to use `std::invoke` to treat them uniform.

Try:

```
 template <typename FUNCTION, typename... ARGS>
 void push_function(const FUNCTION &function, const ARGS &...args){
    push_function([function, args...]{ std::invoke(function,args...); });
 }
```

and pass the pointer to object to the push function as the 2nd argument.

If you lack std invoke, use:

```
 template <typename FUNCTION, typename... ARGS>
 void push_function(const FUNCTION &function, const ARGS &...args){
    push_function([function, args...]{ std::cref(function)(args...); });
 }
```

as a way to get the same behaviour.

Comment: `Pool.push_function(std::bind(&ReliableLink::sendMessage, this, m, dst_ip, dst_port, _seq, false));`
Called my function like that and I get this error : `error: void value not ignored as it ought to be
         push_function([function, this, args...]{ std::invoke(function)(args...); });`